# What is the full form of "they did" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the full form of "they did" here? Is it "they did functioned, or even existed"?

> Instead of serving intended rational purposes, modern management techniques contributed to a saga that built external legitimacy and support and kept critics and legislators at bay. The myth afforded breathing space for work to go forward and elevated participants’ spirits and self-confidence. The Polaris story demonstrates the virtues of drama in engaging the attention and appreciation of both internal and external audiences: “An alchemist’s combination of whirling computers, bright-colored charts, and fast-talking public relations officers gave the Special Projects Office a truly effective management system. It mattered not whether the parts of the system functioned, or even existed. It mattered only that certain people, for a certain period of time, believed that they did” (Sapolsky, 1972, p. 129).

[source](https://books.google.com/books?id=nP_dYskywcYC&pg=PT342&lpg=PT342&dq=%22Instead%20of%20serving%20intended%20rational%20purposes%22&source=bl&ots=Ej4hIZIfeW&sig=ACfU3U0Y-s5Sqvp22164CS7vXGEo2s1Amg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ7aLbsvrhAhVCs1kKHUPQAAEQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Instead%20of%20serving%20intended%20rational%20purposes%22&f=false)

Comment: Please enter links to quotes using the **chain icon** when you ask your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the parts of the system

- ... believed that they did = **believed that the parts of the system existed and functioned**.

The whole sentence

> It mattered not whether the parts of the system functioned, or even existed. It mattered only that certain people, for a certain period of time, believed that they did”

It might be more simply given as

> It did not matter if the parts of the system existed.  It did not matter if they [the parts of the system] functioned.  It mattered if certain people, for a certain period of time, believed the parts of the system existed and functioned.